# Is there a name for this kind of "betweenness structure"?

Tags: terminology, order-theory

A homeomorphism $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is *almost* the same thing as an order isomorphism, except that a homeophorphism can also be an order *anti*-isomorphism.

I'm wondering whether there is a natural *first-order* structure "X" which generalizes partial orders (in the sense that order-presering and order-reversing maps would be the prototypical examples of "X morphisms") such that the homeomorphisms $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ are exactly the "X isomorphisms".

So far the most promising approach seems to be consider a *trinary* "betweenness" relation $$\beta(a,b,c) \equiv (a\le b\le c) \lor (c\le b\le a)$$
and look at the category of $\beta$-preserving maps.

Have such structures been studied? Do they have a name? Is there a nice axiomatic characterization of the trinary relations that can be induced by a partial (or total?) order in this way?

Comment: I think some of these are studied under the heading of [ordered geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_geometry). I think the axiomatic geometry guys who study (weakened versions of) Hilbert's fourth problem may have some interesting things to say about this.

Answer (score 4):

There is already something called ["betweeness relation"](http://planetmath.org/BetweennessRelation.html). What's more, it seems to be exactly what you want.

Comment: The planetmath page on betweenness relations has [moved](http://planetmath.org/node/39661).

Answer (score 2):

For my intermediate question about generalizing partial orders to something where order-preserving and order-reversing maps would both be homomorphisms, here is a sort of brute-force way to make a poset forget its orientation:

We consider a *four-way* relation $ab\sim cd$, intuitively meaning "the relation between $a$ and $b$ is the same as the relation between $c$ and $d$", and formally defined by
$$ ab\sim cd ~\equiv~ (a<b\land c<d)\lor(b<a\land d<c) $$
Celarly, if a partial order $P$ has at least one pair of different but comparable elements, then the $\sim$-preserving maps from $P$ to another partial order are exactly the order-preserving maps plus the order-reversing maps. The same is also (somewhat vacuously) true if $P$ is the trivial partial order.

We can give axioms for $\sim$ that guarantee that it derives from a partial order:

1. Outer symmetry: $ab\sim xy ~\Rightarrow~ xy\sim ab$
2. Outer transitivity: $ab\sim xy \land xy\sim pq ~\Rightarrow~ ab\sim pq$
3. Inner symmetry: $ab\sim xy ~\Rightarrow~ ba\sim yx$
4. Inner transitivity: $ab\sim bc ~\Rightarrow~ ab\sim ac$
5. Inner irreflexivity: $\neg(ab\sim xx)$
6. Connectedness: $ab\sim xy \land pq\sim rs ~\Rightarrow~ ab\sim pq \lor ab\sim qp$

For any $\sim$ that satisfies these axioms we can derive a partial order that induces it: If $\sim$ is the empty relation, then the trivial partial order works. Otherwise choose fixed $a$ and $b$ such that $ab\sim pq$ for some $p$ and $q$ and define $x<y$ to mean $ab\sim xy$. Then $x<y$ is a strict partial order, and $\sim$ is the quaternary relation induced by it.

But elegant it ain't. In particular the connectedness axiom looks rather ad-hoc. (On the other hand, this could be a sign that deleting this axiom might lead to something interesting *beyond* just posets).

I'm still curious whether something interesting can be done with the "betweenness" idea, though.

Answer (score 2):

Not enough points to comment, so I post this as an answer:

Maybe the thing you want is a *partial cyclic order*. See the paper http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1976-82-02/S0002-9904-1976-14020-7/S0002-9904-1976-14020-7.pdf. It seems that there is not much known about these relations.

Answer (score 1):

Concepts along these lines have certainly been studied over a long period of time. A good place to look is S. Adeleke and P. M. Neumann *Relations related to betweenness: their structure and automorphisms*, Memoirs of the AMS, Vol. 131 No. 623 (1998). They consider various structures of this sort, ($B$-sets and betweenness relations), as well as their relationship with semilinearly ordered sets, a natural structure arising from the maximal chains of semilinearly ordered sets, and another structure on the set of ends of a $B$-set.

Another keyword to look up is *pretree*. Brian Bowditch for one has studied them (they arise in his study of the boundary of hyperbolic groups). See his memoir *Treelike structures arising from continua and convergence groups*, Memoirs of the AMS, Vol. 139 No. 662 (1999).